# How can I add an application icon to Gnome app launch menu

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, .desktop

I recently installed an application (VueScan) on Ubuntu 20.04.
Works great but I noticed there is no icon in the Gnome app launch menu.  I have to execute the program from the terminal.
Once the application (VueScan) is up and running, it works great but I noticed that the icon in the dock is missing too.

Any way I can add a missing icon for an app in the dock and create an app icon in the Gnome app launch menu?